# Bootstrap input type="number" doesn't do anythying

Tags: php, html, input

I have a form that I need to force users to input numbers into.  However, the following doesn't work

```
<input type="number" name="price[<?=$custom_item->quote_items_id?>]" value="" placeholder="$">
```

I can hit submit no matter what I type in.  Is this a bootstrap thing? I thought it was a html5 thing that couldn't be overridden.  If I change it to email it will force an email.  Any suggestions?

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Have a look at [Can I use...](http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on if/how the browser implements this feature.

You can check HTML5/CSS3 support for various browsers at [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/). Here's the [entry for the number input type](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number).

**Edit:** You can also check the HTML5 inputs and attributes for the browser you're actually using [on this page](http://www.miketaylr.com/code/input-type-attr.html).

Comment: Gracias.  I guess I'll just have to check it with jquery... Thanks